# Binding android objects to JavaScript

Tags: android

Does android have any framework like **javax.script**, that allows programmer to bind objects made in Java code with some JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a framework to do this. Android's WebView can bind any Java object very easily using the "addJavascriptInterface" method. Example:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaObject(), "myobj");
```

All you would have to do is create the "MyJavaObject" class that contains the methods you want to access in JavaScript. The "myobj" string is the variable you would reference in your JavaScript code to access your Java object. Example:

MyJavaObject.java:

```
...
public int add(int parm1, int parm2) {
    return parm1 + parm2;
}
...
```

JavaScript:

```
...
var val = myobj.add(1,2);
...
```

You shouldn't need to do anything special if you are accessing HTML bundled with your APK. If your app relies on HTML hosted elsewhere you will have to create a custom WebViewClient in your WebView and override the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method (hint: return true). Code:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    ...
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond. But this variant isn't suitable for me. What if I want to execute JavaScript code without using HTML, I mean if I have got *.js* file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach I've seen is to use [Rhino](http://mozilla.org/rhino), which is Mozilla's Javascript interpreter written in Java, which also provides automatic Javascript bindings to Java objects. You'll have to run it in interpreted, rather than compiled, mode (since compiled mode generates Java bytecode which can't be dynamically loaded on Android), but it's very simple to get started with.